# Synchronous simple command stops test run

Tags: nightwatch.js

I've written tons of Nightwatch custom commands which use `execute` and everything has been fine except now I want to do something that doesn't use `execute` or any of the element API.

I've found that in it's simplest form like below, it breaks all my tests from running. The callback is triggered but no subsequent tests will run, and the `after` callback is not called. As soon as I do something that uses the element API in this command, everything is fine.

```
// getTest.js command
exports.command = function (callback) {
  // this.execute(function () {}, [], function () {}); uncomment this and everything works
  if (typeof callback === 'function') {
    callback.call(this, 'test');
  }
  return this;
};

module.exports = {
'this test does run': client => {
    client
      .getTest((res) => {
         console.log(res); // 'test'
      });
  },

  'nope, this will not run': client => {
    console.log('Please run!'); // NOPE
  }
};
```

Comment: Can't you use `execute` or `perform` anyway, since using these seems to solve the issue for you? Or do you run in to problems when using these functions?

Comment: All I need to do is read a CSV. I don't actually want to execute anything in the webpage.

Comment: Matt was right, this is definitely a bug, may be because of a timeout function. I upvoted  ,this is cool, post this on github